# Django doesn't understand if my field in the database is empty

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

So I am working on an API. A GET request which has a condition so as to generate render one field or the other. But to my surprise, `is None` does not work for a field that is empty. How do I solve this problem?

**Here is my table for example**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ms        | offer_id  | priprity_one  | priority_two  |  priority_three
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 89899     |           | priority_one  | priority_two  |  priority_three
| 32323     | 3021      | priority_one  | priority_two  |  priority_three
| 12321     | 3022      | priority_one  | priority_two  |  priority_three
| 43421     | 3023      | priority_one  | priority_two  |  priority_three
```

**views.py**

```
from mamo.models import Mamo
from rest_framework import generics
from mamo.serializers import MamoSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from IPython import embed


class OfferView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MamoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'ms'

    def get_queryset(self):
        msisdn = self.kwargs['ms']
        try:
            return Mamo.objects.filter(ms=ms)
        except Mamo.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)

        if serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is not None:
            result = serializer.data[0]['priority_one']
        elif serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is None: # This line dont work
            result = serializer.data[0]['priority_two']
        else:
            result = serializer.data[0]['priority_three']
        return Response(result)
```

**models.py**

```
class Basic(models.Model):
    ms = models.BigIntegerField(db_index=True, blank=False, help_text="Customer")
    offer_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    priority_one = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=True, default='cleaner')
    priority_two = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=True, default='cleaner')
    priority_three = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=False, default='cleaner') 

    class Meta:
        #ordering = ('ms',)
        db_table = 'offer_table'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ms
```

To make it work, this is what I have done below, but I believe it doesn't make sense. I will prefer any other way around it.

```
    if len(serializer.data[0]['offer_id']) > 0:
        result = serializer.data[0]['eligible_offer']
    elif len(serializer.data[0]['offer_id']) == 0:
        result = serializer.data[0]['market_offer']
    else:
        result = serializer.data[0]['informational_offer'] 
    return Response(result)
```

Note
I am using DRF. I also called `is empty` on that part that doesn't work, it still didn't work. **Meaning when the field in the database is empty as I have shown in the database**, `elif serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is None` **condition part should take effect but didn't respond**.

I used `embed` to debug it and this is what I get:

```
n [11]: serializer.data[0]['offer_id']
Out[11]: u''

In [12]: serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is None
Out[12]: False

In [13]:  serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is empty
Out[13]: False
```

Comment: First, show your models. Secondly, explain what "doesn't work" means; what *exactly* happened?

Comment: Also, if you just want to return a single field, why are you using a serializer at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman am returning `priority_one`, `priority_two`, `priority_three` depending on the if..else condition. Just one.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM offer_table WHERE offer_id is null and ms = 89899`

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM offer_table WHERE offer_id = '' and ms = 89899`

Comment: why you think the field is NULL?

Comment: Yes. So, like I say, what's the point of the serializer? Why not just check the value in the model and return the relevant field?

Comment: Can you show me? Am still a Django noob. Are using saying I don't need a serializer when am using DRF?

Comment: I have posted my models.py file. look again.

Comment: You should not use `null=True` on a `CharField`. By default a `CharField` will be the empty string, not null. You would have to set it explicitly to null to save it that way. If it's unset, it'll be saved as '' to the db. This would give you two possible empty values: '' and NULL. Just check for the empty string instead of `is None` and remove null=True from your model definition.

Comment: @dirkgroten so you suggest I remove `null=True` from all I have in the models.py?

Comment: Alternatively, since it looks like `offer_id` is always an integer, use an `IntegerField`, which can be null. In that case, not setting it means `NULL` will be saved and you will be able to check `is None`.

Comment: From `CharField`, yes. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#null).

Comment: @dirkgroten.  Thank you. Your advice actually worked. You might wanna develop that so I can accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is all very confused.

Your basic problem is that the field contains an empty string, not a NULL value. Those are not the same. If you used the Pythonic `if serializer.data[0]['offer_id']` rather than explicitly comparing with None then this would just work. In any case, you should not allow `null=True` on CharFields.

Your larger problem is that you have completely confused about various components in DRF do. `ListAPIView` is for returning a list of items, and its `get` method is concerned with showing that list. The list should consist of the serialized queryset. For some reason you are using this to return a single field of a single item - the first one in the database. This doesn't make any sense.

Additionally, the serializer is for returning to the user the serialized data. For whatever reason, you don't want to do that, you want to return a single field. Therefore, there is *no reason* to use a serializer here. You should just check the value of the model. So:

```
item = self.get_queryset().first()

if item.offer_id:
   result = item.priority_one
 ...
```

Comment: But is this not hard-coding the response by using `.first`. Don't forget am using filter() to pick the match from the database. Offer_id could be empty anywhere in the database

Comment: Also, I believe using DRF's `ListAPIView` can also help you list just a single item rather than all list if am right?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. That's exactly what you did in the original code with `serializer.data[0]`. And no, if you want a single item you should use [`RetrieveAPIView`'](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) or one of the other views that include the RetrieveModelMixin.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will use `RetrieveAPIView`. Thanks notifying me of that blunder.